# How to access a Rails controller view context from outside of a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actioncontroller, actionviewhelper

I am working on cleaning up some code that relies on some custom controller helper methods, by creating a "plain old Ruby" presenter object. In my controller, I am able to pass the view context to the class:

```
def show
  # old code: view_context.bad_helper_method
  @foobar = FoobarPresenter.new(Foobar.find(params[:id]), view_context)
end

class FoobarPresenter
  def initialize(model, view_context)
    @model = model
    @view_context = view_context
  end

  def something
    @view_context.bad_helper_method
  end
end
```

However, I'm not sure what to pass in my test. I would rather pull the helper/view_context dynamically so that I don't have to pass it in.

How can I access the view/controller helper context outside of the controller?

This is a Rails 3.2 project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about testing the expectations?

1. Test for controller (note that `subject` is the instance of the controller, assuming we're testing using `rspec-rails`):

   ```
   view_context     = double("View context")
   foobar_presenter = double("FoobarPresenter")

   allow(subject).to receive(:view_context).and_return(view_context)
   allow(FoobarPresenter).to receive(:new).with(1, view_context).and_return(foobar_presenter)

   get :show, id: 1

   expect(assigns(:foobar)).to eql(foobar_presenter)
   ```
2. Test for presenter:

   ```
   view_context = double('View context', bad_helper_method: 'some_expected_result')
   presenter    = FoobarPresenter.new(double('Model'), view_context)

   expect(presenter.something).to eql('some_expected_result')
   ```

Comment: I think this is probably the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Simpler than you think! (I lost almost an hour until I found a way)

You can instantiate an ActionView

```
_view_context = ActionView::Base.new
```

and use it in your test

```
FoobarPresenter.new(Foobar.new, _view_context)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to instantiate one in a rails console, and this did it for me.

Comment: In modern rails (eg 6.1), `ActionView::Base.new` says `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 3)`

Comment: In Rails 7, you can use the controller to create one i.e: `_view_context = InvoicesController.new.view_context`.

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately don't have a perfect answer for you.  However, I've dug through the Draper Decorator library, and they have solved this problem.

In particular, they have a HelperProxy class and a ViewContext class that seem to automatically infer the context that you want.

https://github.com/drapergem/draper

They also have some specs around both of these classes, which I'm sure you could borrow from in setting up your own specs.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll dig through the source and see if I can find something.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/view-context-in-specs/213470/5) the following (a bit modified version) worked for me:

1. Add the following to `rails_helper.rb`

```rb
config.include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior, file_path: %r{spec/presenters}
```

(assuming your presenter classes are located in the `/presenters` folder)

2. After this you can access the view context in your specs via the `view` method:

```rb
FoobarPresenter.new(Foobar.new, view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's only available from within the controllers, however, it's fairly easy to create it.

```
class ViewContextDelegator
  RouteHelpers = Module.new { delegate_missing_to 'Rails.application.routes.url_helpers' }
  HELPERS = ApplicationController.helpers.extend(RouteHelpers)
  delegate_missing_to(:HELPERS)
end
```

Then use it in any file as follows:

```
ViewContextDelegator.new.time_ago_in_words(Time.now)
# "less than a minute"
ViewContextDelegator.new.root_path
# "/"
```

or in a spec:

```
subject { described_class.new(arg1, view_context) }
let(:view_context) { ViewContextDelegator.new }
```

Alternatively, you can just define a test helper if you only need it for testing purposes.

```
def view_context
  @view_context ||= ApplicationController
                    .helpers
                    .extend(Module.new { delegate_missing_to 'Rails.application.routes.url_helpers' })
end
```